# Static Root and Static Url confusion in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to read create mp3 files in django. but I am confused about static and static_root that I have configured. 
WHat happening is that in my code at a point when I print the below line it shows 
**/usr/local/src/mena_recording/play/static/audio/dorris_0_.mp3**

code:

```
print settings.BASE_DIR+'/play/static/audio/'+record.driverName +'_'+str(counter)+'_'+ '.mp3'
```

but when I use the same thing in the next line in this piece it gives this error:

```
IOError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/usr/local/src/mena_recording/play/static_root/play/static/audio/dorris_0_.oga'
```

code:

```
with open(settings.BASE_DIR+'/play/static/audio/'+record.driverName +'_'+str(counter)+'_'+ '.mp3', 'w') as mp3_file:
    mp3_file.write(decoded_mp3_str)
    mp3_file.close()
```

**my settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'play/static_root')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mena_recording/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'play/static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Would someone enlighten me please how this works ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try editigng STATIC_ROOT to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'play/')`

Comment: @mu無 your comment helped. Its Working now, but can you please tell me How Django was converting an actual path to Static_root path ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the django docs,

[`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) is the absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.

[`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url) is the URL to use when referring to static files located in `STATIC_ROOT`.

So, when you request some specific static resource, it is searched in `STATIC_ROOT + STATIC_URL` and then served.

Now in your problem, you do

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'play/static_root')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

which means django would have effectively been searching in `BASE_DIR/play/static_root/static/` which would be incorrect, so looking at other paths you can figure out that you need to do

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'play/')
```