# staticfile is not working on other page, but index

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python on Django. I am making a simple website, but I have a problem with staticfile. I can make it load boostrap and some images on static folder, but it just work correctly when it is in index page, if I click to other page, staticfile is not working anymore. This is my setting.py. pls tell me what I have to do to solve this problem, thanks

This is my setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/static/static_root/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
)
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    list_post_Anh = Blog.objects.filter(category_id=1).order_by('-posted')
    list_post_Uc = Blog.objects.filter(category_id=2).order_by('-posted')
    list_post_Ca = Blog.objects.filter(category_id=3).order_by('-posted')
    list_post_Us = Blog.objects.filter(category_id=4).order_by('-posted')

    context = {'listbloganh':list_post_Anh, 'listbloguc':list_post_Uc, 'listblogca':list_post_Ca, 'listblogus':list_post_Us}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def view_post(request, slug):
    getpost = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    context = {'post':getpost}
    return render(request, 'content.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'WebDuHoc.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^baiviet/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$', 'blog.views.view_post', name='content'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: 1. Please don't post screenshots; it's code, post the actual text. 2. That is not nearly enough information. Where is the code for the view? And the template? Are you in DEBUG mode? Have you run collectstatic?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok thanks, I fixed my post. I ran it on DEBUG mode. I ran collectstatic already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I use this (I am new in Django but it works for me):

**settings.py**

```
"""
    Django settings for simplesite project.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
    """

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os
    import simplesite
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                     os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates").replace ('\\','/'),
    )



    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '8x*)8mtzd86&634n=kt!gr=9m**916trc&wd*qb(4uvgpcad3n'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True


    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'bootstrap3',              
        'django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3',
        'django_admin_bootstrapped',         
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'homepage',
        'simpleapp',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    )

    # http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html
    BOOTSTRAP3= {

                'base_url': '/static/bootstrap3',
                'css_url': '/static/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css',

    }


    SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'simplesite.urls'

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'simplesite.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/
    # default language, it will be used, if django can't recognize user's language
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    # list of activated languages
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', 'English'),
        ('it', 'Italian'),
    )


    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    # enable django’s translation system
    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # specify path for translation files
    LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'locale'), 
    )


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    )



    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin


admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',                       
                       url(r'^', include('homepage.urls')), 
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^', include('simpleapp.urls')),      
)
```

**some.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{%block content%}
...
<script  src="{% static 'jquery-1.11.2.js' %}"></script>  //here I call js files which I put in static folder
<script src="{% static 'js/conta.js' %}"></script>
<a href="{% url 'conta' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" id="btnGo">GO</a><div id="loading"></div>
...
{% endblock content %}
```

**example of directory tree**

```
MyProject
    -MyProject
        -settings.py
        -...
    -MyApp
        - ...
    -static
        -js
           -...
    -manage.py
    -...
```

Also look at [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470089/static-root-and-static-url-confusion-in-django).

Comment: I'm happy for you ;-)