# How to access media through URL after uploading

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a blog application, where every post has a featured image. When I upload the image from admin dashboard, I can see the image in my folder. But, when i try to access the url of the image or show the image from source, it's showing nothing.

Here is my code:

****models.py****

```
class Post(models.Model):
    PRIVACY=(
        ('0', 'Public'),
        ('1', 'Private')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery/")
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=PRIVACY, default='0')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=58,blank=True,) 


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug_save(self) # call slug_save, listed below
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('src:post_detail',args=[self.slug])
    def get_image(self):
        return self.image.url
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-published')
    template = 'home.html'
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, template, context)

def post_detail(request,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post)
    return render(request,'detail.html',{'post': post})
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'src'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    ]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

****home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
  <section class="post">
          <h3><a class="post-title"
              href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
              {{ post.title }}
          </a></h3>
          <span class="post-meta">
              {{ post.published }}
            <a href="{{post.get_image}}">
              <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" /></a>
          </span>
          <p class="post-excerpt">
              {{ post.description }}
          </p>
  </section>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}**
```

When I try to access some files directly from the image url:
[image]

This is the urls.py of my root project :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('site/', include('src.urls')),
]
```

This is in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: what do you have your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL set to?

Answer (score 1):

In your setting.py do you have MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. Please check that and if you dont have add like this:
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'

##where you have your file stored in media folder inside your root folder

Answer (score 0):

`MEDUA_URL = '/media/'` looks to be spelled wrong. Change to
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Also try putting

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in your main urls.py instead of your app urls

And your STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL should not be the same. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25470089/8599404) for more info

Comment: Still facing same issue :'(

Comment: is your image saving to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/gallery/icon.png` ?

Comment: Yes. Image is saving.

Comment: did you add static urlpatterns to your root urls as in my answer? Try uploading a new image after these changes